# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context error in PHP

Tags: php

I need to get values of html element name 'item_name1','item_name2','item_name3'...so on using loop. But it is showing this fatal error. Please help to resolve...
Code is:

```
 $item_name = array();
 $item_qty = array();
 $item_value = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=php_count;$i++){
     $item_name($i) =  $_POST['item_name+$i'];
     $item_qty($i) =  $_POST['item_qty+$i'];
     $item_value($i) =  $_POST['item_value+$i'];
    echo($item_name($i));
 }
```

Comment: Error is showing at line  -  $item_name($i) =  $_POST['item_name+$i'];

Comment: `$item_name[$i]` do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need square brackets `[ ]` instead of parentheses `( )` when accessing your arrays. The former are used for array indexing while the latter are used for function calls.

Since you are essentially calling your array like a function and you have the result of that call on the left-hand side of an assignment, you are getting the error that you can't write to a function return value.

And by the way: Currently you are literally accessing the indexes `item_name+$i` and such of `$_POST` because you have the `+$i` part *inside* of the string. Use `$_POST['item_name' + $i]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code have to like this

```
 $item_name[$i] =  $_POST['item_name'.$i];
 $item_qty[$i] =  $_POST['item_qty'.$i];
 $item_value[$i] =  $_POST['item_value'.$i];
 echo($item_name[$i]);
```

Comment: 'item_qty+$i' will not work due to it not processing the $i in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

## as requested

- use square brackets for array elements
- use double quotes to allow variable processing within string context
- use variable for php count

  ```
   $item_name = array();
   $item_qty = array();
   $item_value = array();
    for($i=1;$i<=$items_count;$i++){
     $item_name[$i]=  $_POST[“item_name+$i”];
     $item_qty[$i] =  $_POST[“item_qty+$i”];
     $item_value[$i] =  $_POST[“item_value+$i”];
    echo($item_name[$i]);
   }
  ```

———

## alternative solution

### simplify by changing your form input names to allow arrays of data

Input names such as `item[0][name]` would allow you to simply loop through an item array!

```
foreach($_POST['item'] as $item) {
    $item_name = $item['name'];
    ...
```